# get data for a record in the past

Tags: sql, db2, logical-operators, toad

I have 2 tables, table1 and table2.

**What I want to achieve:**

I want to return the current month info about an employee

AND

when they created an account from table 2. They might be have changed their position as of today so I want to capture info at a point in time and current on the **same row.**

College program table

```
Table 1
Name  Acct_Cr_DT
a1    12/1/2018
b1    1/4/2018
c1    5/6/2018
```

Last Month (12/29) and current Month Data (1/29/2019). Assuming data refreshes on last day of every fiscal month.

```
Table 2
Name  position  gender  Emp status  FISCAL_MONTH_END_DATE
a1    Analyst   M       hourly      12/29/2018
b1    Intern    F       hourly      12/29/2018
c1    Director  F       hourly      12/29/2018
a1    Manager   M       hourly      1/29/2019
b1    Analyst   F       hourly      1/29/2019
c1    Director  F       hourly      1/29/2019
```

a1 was an analyst at the time of account creation.
b1 was an intern at the time of account creation.

**Sample output:** Need the info at the time of account creation before these got a promotion.

```
Name  Acct_Cr_DT  position  gender  Emp status  FISCAL_MONTH_END_DATE
a1    12/1/2018   Analyst   M       hourly      1/29/2019
b1    1/4/2018    Intern    F       hourly      1/29/2019
c1    5/6/2018    Director  F       hourly      1/29/2019
```

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: How do you calculate `position, gender, Emp status` for some particular `Name` in the *Sample output*? Is this from the earliest date in `Table 2` for this `Name`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this own my own.

```
Basically you'll have to join on Name and make sure the "Acct Create DT" is 
<=FISCAL_MONTH_END_DATE" to get the info for point in time for that employee.

Now after that, create a sub-query with a LEFT JOIN on Table 2 and extract the current 
"FISCAL_MONTH_END_DATE" to return current month data
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the current month info for table 1:

```
SELECT *
FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE MONTH(COLUMN_NAME) = MONTH(GETDATE())
AND YEAR(COLUMN_NAME) = YEAR(GETDATE())
```

However, judging your from your explanations, you need a join statement **to capture info at a point in time and current on the same row**. So you probably need this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_1 a inner join TABLE_2 b on a.id=b.id
WHERE MONTH(COLUMN_NAME) = MONTH(GETDATE())
AND YEAR(COLUMN_NAME) = YEAR(GETDATE())
```

Please provide sample output for further explanation.

Comment: I added the output, please check

Comment: Getting this error - No authorized routine named "GETDATE" of type "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found.

Comment: I'm using toad and connected to db2

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640697/how-do-i-display-current-date-and-time-in-toad-for-oracle) Please refer to this link. To get current datetime in toad

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try the following query.

SELECT TB1.name,Acct_Cr_DT,position,gender,Emp status,FISCAL_MONTH_END_DATE 
FROM Table1 tb1
INNER JOIN Table2 tb2 ON tb1.name=tb2.name
WHERE DATEPART(YEAR,Acct_Cr_DT) = DATEPART(YEAR,FISCAL_MONTH_END_DATE) AND DATEPART(MONTH,FISCAL_MONTH_END_DATE)='12' AND DATEPART(DAY,FISCAL_MONTH_END_DATE)='29'

Getting record at the time of account creation and also the last day of the year which was the record refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to solve this using the wonderful DB2 OLAP functions (aka window functions).

The following code use a subquery to pull out the first position of each employee and sort the records by fiscal end of month. The outer query then joins the results with `table2` to get the employee hire date, and filters the records corresponding to the most recent fiscal end of month.

```
SELECT 
    tx.name, tx.first_position, tx.gender, tx.emp_status, tx.fiscal_month_end_date, t1.acct_cr_dt
FROM (
    SELECT
        t2.*,
        FIRST_VALUE(t2.position) OVER(PARTITION BY t2.name ORDER BY fiscal_month_end_date) first_position,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY t2.fiscal_month_end_date desc) rnk
    FROM table2 t2
  ) tx INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.name = tx.name
 WHERE tx.rnk = 1;
```

In this **[DB Fiddle demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/StUwYG9TUUf5G2VDr5S3C/0)**, the query yields :

```
| name | first_position | gender | emp_status | fiscal_month_end_date | acct_cr_dt |
| ---- | -------------- | ------ | ---------- | --------------------- | ---------- |
| a1   | Analyst        | M      | hourly     | 2019-01-29            | 2018-12-01 |
| b1   | Intern         | F      | hourly     | 2019-01-29            | 2018-01-04 |
| c1   | Director       | F      | hourly     | 2019-01-29            | 2018-05-06 |
```

NB : this a MySQL 8.0 fiddle, since there is no DB2 db fiddlde available in the wild...